# Merge and create tables using a loop

Tags: r, loops, merge

I tried to search for how to merge and create multiple tables using a loop but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I have four tables: tables 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, and table 2.

Tables 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 share the same column but have different rows.

Table 2 shares the same first column as tables 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3.

To be specific, the tables look as follows.

table 1.1

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

table 1.2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |
| 6 | f |

table 1.3

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | g |
| 8 | h |
| 9 | i |

table 2

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | Z |
| 4 | p |
| 5 | q |
| 6 | r |
| 7 | s |
| 8 | t |
| 9 | u |

I would like to merge table 1.1 with table 2, table 1.2 with table2, and table 1.3 with table 2 using a loop so that there are three different tables in the end.

To be specific, I would like to get as follows.

table 1.1'

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 2 | b | y |
| 3 | c | z |

table 1.2'

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | d | p |
| 5 | e | q |
| 6 | f | r |

table 1.3'

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | g | s |
| 8 | h | t |
| 9 | i | u |

What would be the best way to get this?
I would like to know how to use loops in this situation because my actual data contains tables 1.1 to 1.100 and table 2, and I will have to merge 100 times and create 100 tables.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Do you have space between the objects names i.e. `table 1.1` or is it `table1.1`?

Comment: Thank you for asking! No, I don't have space between the object names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `lapply` after placing the 'table1.1', 'table1.2', 'table1.3', ... in a `list` (with `mget`) to loop over the `list` and then do an inner join with `merge` from `base R` and return a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0("table1.", 1:100))
# or if there is space in the object names
# lst1 <- mget(paste0("table 1.", 1:100))
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) merge(x, table2))
```

Comment: Thank you for showing and explanation. When it comes to lists, it is still not that easy for me. here is the `tidyverse` equivalent: `map(lst1, ~left_join(., table2))`